# Right way to reference platform-specific types in isomorphic Typescript library

Tags: node.js, typescript, isomorphic-javascript

I'm trying to write a Typescript library that I'd like to be able to include when targeting both the browser and Node.  I have two problems: referring to platform-specific types in the body of the code, and the inclusion of those types in the generated `.d.ts` declarations that accompany the transpiled JS.

In the first case, I want to write something like

```
  if (typeof window === "undefined") {
    // Do some Node-y fallback thing
  } else {
    // Do something with `window`
  }
```

This fails to compile if I don't include `"dom"` in my `lib` compiler option (that is, if I just say `lib: ["es2016"]` in `tsconfig`), because the global `window` is not defined.  (Using `window` is just an example of something out of `lib.dom.d.ts`, it may also be `fetch` or a `Response` or `Blob`, etc.)  The point is that the code should already be safe at runtime by checking for the existence of the global object before using it, it's the type side that I can't figure out.

In the second case, I'm getting an error trying to include the library after it builds.  I can build the library using `"dom"` in the `lib` option, and the resulting output includes typings with e.g. `declare export function foo(x: string | Blob): void`.  The problem is, if the consuming code doesn't include a definition for `Blob` (no `"dom"` lib), it fails to compile, even though it's only actually calling `foo` with a `string` (or not using `foo` at all!).

I don't want my library (or the consumer) to try to pollute the global namespace with fake `window` or `Blob` declarations if I can help it.  More isometric libraries have been popping up but I haven't found a good Typescript example to follow.  (If it's too complex a topic for SO, I'd still greatly appreciate a pointer to documentation or an article/blog post.)

Comment: Usually, this is done by extracting the business logic in a separate file, and then writing another file (for each supported platform) with the logic of invoking the functionality. Can you do this in your setup?

Comment: Refs: [ms/TS#39100 (comment)](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/39100#issuecomment-645458394), [ms/TS#31894](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31894)

Comment: I found some interesting leads that are too long to fit in a comment, and I haven't fully worked out a perfect solution with them so I don't want to write up an answer yet.  The short version is that you can write libraries with `import`s preceded by `//@ts-ignore` and if the import specifier does not exist, you get an alias for `any`. Couple that with [this request I made](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript-DOM-lib-generator/issues/1207) and you could try to import the browser version of `Blob` and get `any` if it's not available in the current environment.

Comment: This one seems fitting as well: [ms/TS#3538](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3538)

Comment: Another place where this question came up: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/issues/2896

Answer (score 2):

In response to your clarifying comments, I now understand your question to be: "How can I use global types from an environment without including those environment type libraries in my own library?"

---

A truly isomorphic module is agnostic to the environment.

You should simply define the types that you intend to use from TS language built-ins. In this way, your code targets literal shapes, not environments.

This is not terse, however, a positive side-effect of this method is that your code will never break because of updates to an environment's library declaration files.

**You can use documentation and examples to explain how to use library types with your modules.**

Here are some (contrived) examples:

---

When typing parameters, use types which represent only the parts of the values which you actually use in your code:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/PQKhFgCgAIWgJApgJ0QGmgAwG4EMA2AroptAJYDO0FALsmQHYDmGA9stLg9KwEYBWiAMY1oNAJ4AHRNADuACzJD55KogAeNRAwAmiHdF7jO3RrS5DEUWDwBmWJvj4EAKoooA6AEJPepRpyGyKyyFCgAXNYgwFC4FOIMQtC2hIk0ZKzccS4aogAUeESI4dR0jEzQAD7QAN5iuXkAlCUACsEAtpSIADy09MwAfNAAvs3QbaydYb1lg7XW0Kg0hMjcEtKs9oXE0AC8+9AA5H3lh9AA-NDbMiXXHlqaTQDcUMNPQA)

```ts
/**
 * Here, `value` is string, or an object type which is extended by an instance
 * of `globalThis.Blob` in a browser:
 */
async function asText (value: string | { text(): Promise<string> }): Promise<string> {
  return typeof value === 'string' ? value : value.text();
};
```

---

When returning values from (or which use) global library types from an environment, test for the existence and shape of the value (structurally, just like TypeScript does), and then use utilities to get the types directly from the environment:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBA4gKlAvFUkD2AzKBzANmgIwENc4ALASwGcBuAWAChVoAFAJzTADUSBXCADxwANFADSAPiTioEAB7AIAOwAmVKAGsIITFAQB+PQG0xAXSgAuKEogA3CG3oNGGXkoDGwCmiU4IwAHUKVTQAdwAxf3cyKAAKAEordk4eXH4BeFEAcgwosiypAG9GKCgKLFjmXVi8QhJyaigidSIlEHiAOlDglTD9DtzgaKgAQkRkHLdPbyUs+KhihlLS4DIOUOsIDbhwCABRNg42WKzukNCBvOs0YDLfKndOCDmnUoBfEqg2f142Xxr8MRSJQWi02p0zr1Qv1BsNmlBktw+IJMlAcnkCk4Ps4GM0QB4oK4PF4fIS8gAhQFxX64KxUYBsYLYRIIjgAW2oggAkkp6a13BAdpABIjUulUVlKYQChIip9HrzblhkNh-EFzpEhmQEjQoAB6PVQAAGVSwtSBDSoly1RruUAI6yoDj1ABFlGhRK0VMabPY2LbglAAHJoFTQWLdXC4FBrMLxeU+elfCBUMCJ6DIIihIgUJWxGnxV7J4C-XzfVPpjoEQEJJrqZIcp0CHl8jyC3YijhItIokRoqUEGUSLGMRgKpPVwjSWFkAcnNAaF76w1GhucgQDiQB3wOsJOtiu92e1Q+uwObfB0PhyPR1breJAA)

```ts
type GT = typeof globalThis;
type PropValue<T, K> = K extends keyof T ? T[K] : never;

function getWindowFetch (): PropValue<GT, 'fetch'> {
  if (typeof (globalThis as any).window?.fetch !== 'function') {
    throw new TypeError('window.fetch not in scope');
  }
  return (globalThis as any).window?.fetch as PropValue<GT, 'fetch'>;
}

async function fetchBlob (url: string): Promise<InstanceType<PropValue<GT, 'Blob'>>> {
  const f = getWindowFetch(); // `typeof globalThis.fetch` in browser/Deno, and `never` in Node (will throw)
  const response = await f(url);
  return response.blob() as Promise<InstanceType<PropValue<GT, 'Blob'>>>;
}

const blob = fetchBlob('ok'); // `Promise<Blob>` in browser/Deno, and `never` in Node (will throw)
```

---

A classic example: base64 string conversion functions:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#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)

```ts
function utf8ToB64 (utf8Str: string): string {
  if (typeof (globalThis as any).window?.btoa === 'function') { // browser/Deno
    return (globalThis as any).window.btoa(utf8Str);
  }
  else if (typeof (globalThis as any).Buffer?.from === 'function') { // Node
    return (globalThis as any).Buffer.from(utf8Str).toString('base64');
  }
  throw new TypeError('Runtime not supported');
}

function b64ToUtf8 (b64Str: string): string {
  if (typeof (globalThis as any).window?.atob === 'function') { // browser/Deno
    return (globalThis as any).window.atob(b64Str);
  }
  else if (typeof (globalThis as any).Buffer?.from === 'function') { // Node
    return (globalThis as any).Buffer.from(b64Str).toString('utf8');
  }
  throw new TypeError('Runtime not supported');
}

utf8ToB64('héllo world'); // 'aOlsbG8gd29ybGQ='
b64ToUtf8('aOlsbG8gd29ybGQ='); // 'héllo world'
b64ToUtf8(utf8ToB64('héllo world')); // 'héllo world'
```

How you decide to structure your library and its exports depends on your preferences.

Comment: So to use the library from Node you have to pass `process` to every call?  That seems really clumsy -- are there examples in the wild of real libraries that do this?

Comment: Also: this does not address libraries that must *return* a platform-specific type.  I can't return a "Blob-like" that only specifies the 3-out-of-50 properties and methods that I actually use.

Comment: Re: "_you have to pass `process` to every call?_": I didn't imply that: it was just an example function which accepted a shape _like_ part of Node's `process`. I'll update my answer to address both of your comments.

Comment: Thanks, that clears things up.  I'm still not *very* comfortable about all the any-casting.  Suppose I need to actually *use* some Buffer methods in my library -- your example call to `Buffer.from` is typed as `any` when `tsc` compiles the library. What if I thought the signature was `from(parts: string[])` (like the browser Blob constructor), and so called it as `from([b64Str])`?  Typechecker wouldn't complain, because it has no call signature to check against.  Maybe I could use your `PropValue` construct, and a separate `tsconfig` for each platform?

Comment: That will always be a problem because of the criteria in your question. You can't (1) exclude the library type, AND (2) not re-create and apply it to the method yourself, AND (3) expect to have type safety when using the method.

Comment: That's not strictly true if you have per-platform `tsconfig` files. When building for browser, your Node-specific types should be aliased away as `any`, but when you run a separate build with the other config file, they can be properly defined and typechecked (and the browser-specific types would get aliased away).

Comment: @Coderer Considering the base64 functions above: let’s say the `as any` assertions were removed: In the scenario that you describe, what exactly is going to “_alias away as `any`_” references which don’t exist according to the compiler (e.g. `Buffer` without the Node lib, and `window` without the DOM lib)?

Comment: That's the point of my question.  One option I found is to put a `// @ts-ignore` before an `import` statement -- see my comment on the OP for details.  That way, you could have `tsconfig.node.json` with `lib: ["es6"], types: ["node"]` and `tsconfig.dom.json` with `lib: ["es6", "dom"], types: [ ]`, and I *think* get the behavior I described.

Comment: @Coderer I think you are referencing [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65848540/right-way-to-reference-platform-specific-types-in-isomorphic-typescript-library/70455210?noredirect=1#comment124433571_65848540). (1) Are you implying that you expect the consumer to include `@ts-ignore` when importing your library? (2) Have you tried [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65848540/right-way-to-reference-platform-specific-types-in-isomorphic-typescript-library/70455210?noredirect=1#comment124640491_70455210)? If so, what were the results?

Comment: The consumer wouldn't need `@ts-ignore`, it would be in the `.d.ts` that ships with the library.  If my request goes through, `mylib/index.d.ts` could `import {Blob} from "@types/web"` with a preceding `@ts-ignore`, then consumers with `@types/web` installed would get a `Blob` while those without it would get `any`. I can't actually *try* it without an exported (non-global) `window` / `Buffer` / `Blob` type.

Comment: Interesting workaround with `@ts-ignore` @Coderer. Although for Node consumers, doesn't this disable type checking on input parameters because the typing is effectively `declare export function foo(x: string | any): void`?

Comment: There's a trick for that I proposed in one of the issues I linked to, but there are so many comments I'm not sure which.  Short version is you can write `type MaybeBlob = any extends Blob ? never : Blob;`  This will safely erase itself in a union.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there isn't a great way to do this currently.

The approach [suggested by members of the TypeScript team](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31894) is to take advantage of the interface merging feature of TypeScript, and "forward declare" interfaces in the global scope which can potentially merge with the declarations of the same interface in the consuming environment.

> One common example of this might be the Buffer type built into Node.js. A library that operates in both browser and Node.js contexts can state that it handles a Buffer if given one, but the capabilities of Buffer aren't important to the declarations.
>
> ```
> export declare function printStuff(str: string): void;
>
> /**
>  * NOTE: Only works in Node.js
>  */
> export declare function printStuff(buff: Buffer): void;
> ```
>
> One technique to get around this is to "forward declare" Buffer with an empty interface in the global scope which can later be merged.
>
> ```
> declare global {
>     interface Buffer {}
> }
>
> export declare function printStuff(str: string): void;
>
> /**
>  * NOTE: Only works in Node.js
>  */
> export declare function printStuff(buff: Buffer): void;
> ```

This approach has some problems, as elaborated on in the issue linked above:

- It only works for classes and interfaces, not other types such as union types.
- Interface merging doesn't always correctly resolve conflicts between declarations in two interfaces.

The TypeScript team has proposed a new feature called "Placeholder Type Declarations" to address these issues, but it doesn't appear to be on the roadmap currently.

Comment: I am following the linked issue.  The forward declaration approach works well enough if you're writing typings for a library that you've created in JS, but when you author the library in TS you'd have to manually spell out all the parts of the interface that you use, and trying to *return* the forward-declared type is asking for trouble.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is a classic case for abstraction and a straightforward one. That is, you code against a `IPlatform` interface and refer to that interface in your code. The interface in turn hides all the platform specific implementations.

You can also additionally expose APIs so that consumers can easily initialize the "platform", usually with the appropriate "global" object. Employ dependency injection to inject the correct (platform-specific) instance of `IPlatform` to your code. This should reduce branching in your code severely and keep your code cleaner. You don't have to pollute your code with fake declarations with that approach, as you have pointed out in your question.

Optionally, you can also export the `IPlatform` instance from your package so that the consumers can also reap the benefit of that.

The second problem you mentioned:

> The problem is, if the consuming code doesn't include a definition for Blob (no "dom" lib), it fails to compile, even though it's only actually calling foo with a string (or not using foo at all!).

I think this can be easily countered by installing `@types/node` as devDependency on the consumer side. That should be of relatively low footprint, as that will not add to a consumer's bundle.

Comment: Can you show an example of using DI in this context?  I don't want to introduce a dependency on some kind of DI library, I just want to be able to `import {foo} from "mylib"` and pass it a platform-specific stream type or whatever.

Comment: Also: adding `@types/node` pollutes the global namespace with a bunch of (sometimes conflicting) types if the library is being consumed in a browser environment.  See @jsejcksn 's comment on the original question for issues that have been filed about using triple-slash "ref" directives, which is the "right" (bad) way to do that, and which I'm specifically trying to avoid..

Comment: If you don't have a complex use-case, you don't even have to use any DI lib. You just need to track the configured instance for `IPlatform` and supply that instance wherever you are programming against the `IPlatform` interface.

Comment: Adding the `@types/node` as devDependency should not pollute the global namespace, nor you have to reference the types with triple slash.

Comment: Installing `@types/node` puts new types in your type root (`node_modules/@types`, by default) which means that global-declare modules are included in all builds.  You can try this yourself: add a devDependency, declare a variable of type `Blob`, then use the Language Service (e.g. from VSCode) to "Go To Definition" for the type. You'll see that Blob is a merged declaration from core TS `lib.dom.d.ts` and `@types/node/stream/consumers.d.ts`.

Comment: That's right. Can you explain a bit more, why you think that to be a problem at consumer's end? In my experience, it should not cause that much of an issue. It would be nice to GH repro of the issue you are facing while consuming your package.

Comment: [This writeup](https://gist.github.com/RyanCavanaugh/702ebd1ca2fc060e58e634b4e30c1c1c) includes some examples.  [This change to the types for a popular HTTP API](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/57641) is motivated by similar problems.  There are several other relevant issues linked in comments on the original question.

Comment: I understand your point. In that case, the cleanest solution would be to extract the core functionality to a package and build 2 wrappers around that, for Node.js and for Browser. That way, your consumers can select the platform specific package they want.

Comment: @SayanPal Of course that's the way it's normally done, and [Dima already said that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65848540/right-way-to-reference-platform-specific-types-in-isomorphic-typescript-library/70455210#comment124415754_65848540), but... that's in violation of the question criteria.

Comment: @jsejcksn IMO one should consider the trade-off of current ecosystem before taking design decisions. npm already supports two different platform-specific entry-points, namely `main` and `browser`; some bundlers also support `module`. Unless TS also supports something like that for the typing (which I understand what the strictEnvironment flag might be for), a true isomorphic package might be difficult. Plus segregating the platform specific stuffs, you are also reducing the package size. Having said that, the approach described in my answer still holds.

Comment: I'd still like to see some concrete details in your answer, Sayan -- code, or a link to an example of a project that's built this way.  Something just feels "wrong" about restructuring the whole project to accommodate Typescript's lack of conditional-type/strict-environment support.

Comment: @Coderer you can take a look at Aurelia: https://github.com/aurelia/aurelia. Especially how the tests are run on both node and browser. Hopefully that should give you enough pointers.

Comment: Sayan, that's an enormous monorepo, is there any particular place you're referring to? 
 It appears to transform its own test files using the TS compiler API (in `tests/karma-aurelia-preprocessor`) -- hopefully you're not suggesting every library author write their own Karma plugin. It also appears to include DOM typings in its node tests (in `packages/__tests__/tsconfig.json`), which is exactly what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: @Coderer Take a look at these: https://github.com/aurelia/aurelia/blob/master/packages/__tests__/setup-browser.ts, https://github.com/aurelia/aurelia/blob/master/packages/__tests__/setup-node.ts. As I said also in my answer that the idea is to provide the `globalThis` object from the consumer side. Therefore, the consumer must decide on which platform they want to use your lib.

Comment: The inclusion of "dom" lib in the tsconfig in the aurelia repo is context specific, and might have little to do with your issue. Thus, it might be better not to draw any conclusion from that. Let your consumers decide what all TS lib(s) they want to include.

Comment: The only reason that pattern makes sense in the linked package is that you might want to pass a browser-like environment that isn't actually `globalThis`, in this case, `jsdom`.  That's not a pattern for isomorphic libraries as such, that's a pattern specific to (basically) SSR frameworks.  Very nearly every other type of library shouldn't need the consumer to pass `globalThis`, that's why we have a `globalThis` in the first place.

Comment: Would be nice to know your final solution approach. I am interested to know how do you end up tackling it.

Comment: Just to circle back to this, half a year later: this is still a problem and it's getting worse, because Node keeps adding "DOM-like" (but incompatible!) interfaces in the global namespace.  AFAICT the least worst solution is for Node libraries to avoid using global aliases and always pull classes/interfaces from named modules.