# TSC Compile Error (TS2307) when using the Deno API

Tags: typescript, tsc, deno

I have a little ts project that should be compiled into js.
Since I don't know with which runtime (Deno, Bun or Node) will run, I really need to compile it to js and can not use the Deno built-in compiler.

When I try to compile now the compiler throws an error:

```
 error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Deno'.

Line 34                 version: Deno.version.deno
```

This is my tsconfig file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "types": ["bun-types"]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Do you know how I can fix this issue?

I know I could add `// @ts-ignore` right before but I would prefer to find a proper configuration.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When writing [isomorphic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphic_JavaScript) TypeScript (targeted at multiple runtimes/environments), you won't be able to reliably depend on any values which aren't **common to every environment** without using [feature detection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Tools_and_testing/Cross_browser_testing/Feature_detection). And because of this, you also [can't safely include any ambient library types](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65848540/438273) during compilation — for example: types like Node.js (`@types/node`), Bun (`bun-types`), Deno (`deno.ns`, `deno.window`, etc.), browser/DOM (`@types/web`, `dom`, `dom.iterable`, etc.), or others — which makes it even more complicated.

TypeScript offers a helpful feature called [type predicates](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) that can be used with type guard functions to perform these kinds of validations at runtime — and they'll also inform the compiler that values are of the expected types and are safe to use as such.

You can reference the Deno namespace type declarations at the project's GitHub repository — for example, here's a direct link to the line for `Deno.version.deno` for the current CLI version as I write this answer (`v1.32.4`): https://github.com/denoland/deno/blob/v1.32.4/cli/tsc/dts/lib.deno.ns.d.ts#L4708

In your code, you can feature-detect for the Deno version value like this:

`./src/example.mts`:

```ts
// The following triple-slash directives aren't necessary when using
// the TSConfig in this answer, but I'm including them here so that the module
// can be type-checked in isolation, apart from the config file (e.g. by Deno):
/// <reference no-default-lib="true" />
/// <reference lib="esnext" />
/// <reference path="./types/global.d.ts" />

function isObject<T>(value: T): value is T & object {
  return typeof value === "object" && value != null;
}

// There's a global Deno variable
if ("Deno" in globalThis) {
  // But we don't yet know what type it is
  const { Deno } = globalThis as Record<string, unknown>;
  // It's an object
  if (isObject(Deno)) {
    // And it has a "version" key that's also an object
    if ("version" in Deno && isObject(Deno.version)) {
      // And that object has a "deno" key that's a string
      if ("deno" in Deno.version && typeof Deno.version.deno === "string") {
        // Only in this scope can we safely access it with confidence
        console.log("Deno version:", Deno.version.deno);
      } else {
        console.log(`There's no "deno" string key in Deno.version`);
      }
    } else {
      console.log(`There's no "version" object key in Deno`);
    }
  } else {
    console.log("Deno is not an object");
  }
} else {
  console.log("There's no global Deno");
}
```

---

For completeness, here are the other files in my reproduction directory for your question:

`./package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "so-76034796",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "compile": "tsc"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^5.0.4"
  }
}
```

`./tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "exactOptionalPropertyTypes": true,
    "noImplicitOverride": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,

    "removeComments": true,
    // "inlineSourceMap": true,
    // "inlineSources": true,

    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,

    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleDetection": "force",
    "moduleResolution": "nodenext",
    // "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    // "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,

    "target": "esnext",
    "lib": ["esnext"],

    // "jsx": "react-jsx",

    "outDir": "dist",
    // "noEmit": true,

    "typeRoots": ["./src/types"]
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"]
}
```

> I've included these types from the Console API because it's available in all of the environments mentioned to be targeted. Otherwise, you'd need to feature-detect for it as well:

`./src/types/global.d.ts`:

```ts
/**
 * @see https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v5.0.4/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L17498
 * 
 * For Node.js, refer to:
 * - [global](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/04c9ac7555c9fd1562aea37475af4e176db0019a/types/node/globals.d.ts#L28)
 * - [console](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/04c9ac7555c9fd1562aea37475af4e176db0019a/types/node/console.d.ts#L66)
 */
interface Console {
  assert(condition?: boolean, ...data: any[]): void;
  clear(): void;
  count(label?: string): void;
  countReset(label?: string): void;
  debug(...data: any[]): void;
  dir(item?: any, options?: any): void;
  dirxml(...data: any[]): void;
  error(...data: any[]): void;
  group(...data: any[]): void;
  groupCollapsed(...data: any[]): void;
  groupEnd(): void;
  info(...data: any[]): void;
  log(...data: any[]): void;
  table(tabularData?: any, properties?: string[]): void;
  time(label?: string): void;
  timeEnd(label?: string): void;
  timeLog(label?: string, ...data: any[]): void;
  timeStamp(label?: string): void;
  trace(...data: any[]): void;
  warn(...data: any[]): void;
}

declare var console: Console;
```

Compiling with vanilla `tsc` and running in Node and Deno:

```txt
so-76034796 % npm install

added 1 package, and audited 2 packages in 445ms

found 0 vulnerabilities

so-76034796 % npm run compile

> so-76034796@0.1.0 compile
> tsc

so-76034796 % deno check src/example.mts

so-76034796 % deno run src/example.mts
Deno version: 1.32.4

so-76034796 % deno run dist/example.mjs
Deno version: 1.32.4

so-76034796 % node dist/example.mjs
There's no global Deno

so-76034796 % node --version
v18.16.0

so-76034796 % npm --version
9.5.1

so-76034796 % deno --version
deno 1.32.4 (release, aarch64-apple-darwin)
v8 11.2.214.9
typescript 5.0.3
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! It really help me. 
Never the less I need to call deno and I don't want to check it every time. 

The check "deno in globalThis" is fine. But from that on I'd like to not check further. This is just possible if the compiler knows deno.
Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76034796/tsc-compile-error-ts2307-when-using-the-deno-api/76036976?noredirect=1#comment134133870_76036976) @Krypton What you're saying is this: if `globalThis.Deno` exists, but it is not the one that you expect, then you're ok with runtime errors — is that right?

Comment: Touché! 
Of course not.

The same way I am able to use process.env without any further testing I want to be able to use the deno api. I just want to make sure that I have access to the deno api and then use it. And the compiler should know what the deno api is capable of.

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76034796/tsc-compile-error-ts2307-when-using-the-deno-api/76036976?noredirect=1#comment134134922_76036976) @Krypton "_The same way I am able to use process.env without any further testing_": That's not safe either unless `process.env` is identical in all environments.

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76034796/tsc-compile-error-ts2307-when-using-the-deno-api/76036976?noredirect=1#comment134134922_76036976) @Krypton "_I just want to make sure that I have access to the deno api and then use it. And the compiler should know what the deno api is capable of._": TS only exists at **compile** time (not runtime), so it can't know what's available at runtime — the types that you include and assert during compile time are what the compiler uses to perform analysis of your code and offer diagnostics... (cont.)

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76034796/tsc-compile-error-ts2307-when-using-the-deno-api/76036976?noredirect=1#comment134135499_76036976) That's why feature testing is needed when all target environments aren't controlled/identical.

Comment: Much of the code that we write assumes things about the runtime environment — it's a tradeoff that we make for convenience and performance. Assuming that `globalThis.Deno` is the one you expect isn't much different than assuming that `globalThis.console` is the one that you expect — to what degree you validate each feature/API is up to you.